# Is it possible to "copy" a object from browser console and analyze it?

Tags: javascript

On a Website with a browser game im logging an object to the console.
I can inspect the object, but what i would like to do, if possible, is export or save this object to or into a custom script in order to loop over this object to analyze several proberties of it.

If this is not possible, is it possible to locally alter the JavaScript file my browser is getting from the server so i could replace the console.log() part locally ?

Comment: "im logging an object to the console" So you have access to this script?

Comment: No. Not at this point. If i had, i wouldnt ask this question :D

Comment: Yeah that's what I though so all the answers you got are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Serialize it as JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Deserialize it using:

```
JSON.parse(obj);
```

Comment: how do you access `obj` if it is run into an anonymous function which only logs it to the console ?

Comment: As long as you pass your object to your console, you can output it. Use closure: var old = window.console; window.console = function(arg) { old.call(old, JSON.stringify(arg)); }; I didn't test it, but the idea is to keep a reference to your console and call it after you catch the argument.

Comment: something like [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31934577/3702797) maybe? But I don't see the need to stringify the object if the goal is to "analyze" it with an outer function. Please re-read the question + comments below, you'll find you're out of block. When we see that 4 of 5 other answers are too, we may argue that this is the fault of OP.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have access to the logger script,
you will have to override the `console.log` function, before your script does log your object.

```
(function(){
    //save the original function
    var originalConsoleLog = console.log;

    //override the original console.log
    console.log = function() {
        originalConsoleLog.apply(console, arguments);
        // here you can call your own checking function
        yourCheck(arguments);
    }
})();
```

Now each time an object will be logged to the console, `yourCheck` will be called, with the logged arguments, so you may want to add some sanity check in your own function to be sure you catched the good one.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about Chrome, you can copy whole object to clipboard using `copy(yourObject)` in console.

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#copyobject)

Comment: how do you access `yourObject` if it is run into an anonymous function which only logs it to the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the global `copy` method from the console. For example:

```
var myObjectInTheConsole = {};

copy(myObjectInTheConsole);
```

Tested and works in the most recent versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: how do you access `myObjectInTheConsole` if it is run into an anonymous function which only logs it to the console ?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @roland `JSON.stringify` is exactly what you asked for.

Furthermore, if you are actually looking for how to analysis the data on-the-fly, you can try bookmarklet. A googling on `bookmarklet` will show the details.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if it is from the server..? so as i have practiced i will give a suggestion to find it from the **header's request easily from the developer's tool** just get from there and and beautify it will better to analyze you data.

or you even can use the **fiddler or else tools** that tracks the request and responses with the server.